# Why does this always return false no matter which numbers I plug into the function

Tags: javascript

```js
const compareGuesses = (humanGuess, computerGuess, secretNumber) => {

  let humanGuessDifference = secretNumber - humanGuess
  let computerGuessDifference = secretNumber - computerGuess

  if (computerGuessDifference > humanGuessDifference) {
    var humanWinner = true
  } else {
    var humanWinner = false

  }
  return humanWinner
};

console.log(compareGuesses(1, 10, 2))
```

Comment: returns true if you send `(10, 1, 2)` so ...

Comment: *Why does this always return false no matter which numbers I plug into the function* - It doesn't.

Comment: Perhaps try logging your variable values along the way to better understand the comparisons being made.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't.

```js
const compareGuesses = (humanGuess, computerGuess, secretNumber) => {
  const humanGuessDifference = secretNumber - humanGuess
  const computerGuessDifference = secretNumber - computerGuess
  if (computerGuessDifference > humanGuessDifference) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
console.log(compareGuesses(10, 1, 2))
```

But to properly compare the difference, you should keep in mind that subtraction may result in a negative number - in which case you may get something like `if (1 > -8)` - the magnitude of the difference is larger, but if it's negative, it'll still fulfill the `>`. Use `Math.abs` to take the absolute value of the differences.

```js
const compareGuesses = (humanGuess, computerGuess, secretNumber) => {
  const humanGuessDifference = secretNumber - humanGuess
  const computerGuessDifference = secretNumber - computerGuess
  return Math.abs(humanGuessDifference) < Math.abs(computerGuessDifference);
};
console.log('first is closer:', compareGuesses(10, 1, 2))
console.log('first is closer:', compareGuesses(1, 10, 2))
```

Comment: really appreciate the answer, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much.